# Understanding an If statement in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

I am having problems understanding the following code:

```
public class TestIf {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (true){
            if (false){
                System.out.println("true false");
            }

            else{
                System.out.println("true true");
            }

        }

    }
```

}

When I run this it prints true true.

I don't understand  why this bit of code gets executed in the first place:

```
if(true)
```

If what exactly is true here? It's not like a have declared a boolean, for example

```
boolean bol = true;

if (bol == true) { 
 //execute the rest of the code
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question here.  `if (x)` is essentially short-hand for `if (x == true)`.  So in your case, your first condition is essentially `if (true == true)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If the expression inside `if` gets evaluated to `true`, the `if` is entered.*

```
boolean bol = true;

if (bol == true) {
```

What happens above? Is `bol` equal to `true`? Yes. So `(bol==true)` is equivalent to writing  only `(true)`.

So the above code is same as

```
if (true) {
```

So now consider your code.

```
    if (true){ // enters 'if' since value of expression inside 'if' is true
        if (false){ // goes to else
            System.out.println("true false");
        }

        else{
            System.out.println("true true"); // prints
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your fast reply. Rikayan Bandyopadhyay explanation makes sense to me. I understand how it works now. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(true)
```

Is the same thing as saying no matter what this if statement will always return true. The only time you want to do something like this in an if statement is for quick and dirty testing purposes.

```
if(false)
```

Is the same thing as saying no matter what this if evaluation will always fail. Same as before. You would never do this in real life in an if statement.
Your example of the Boolean is the same exact thing. But in this case you are skipping that extra line of code to declare the Boolean with a *name*. The only reason you declare a variable *with a name* is so you can reuse it later or change it. In this case you are simple placing a Boolean inside the if which will be lost forever as soon as you get out of the if statement.

Sometimes however this true/false evaluation can be useful. For example

```
Boolean test = true;
while(true)
{
//ask for user input...
if(test) break;
}
```

The while will always evaluate true and will forever loop UNTIL it receives a break command. However I don't know any cool tricks with the if statement this way other than running methods from inside the if.

Answer (score 0):

For an `if` statement like:

```
if (condition)
{
    statements1;
}
else
{
    statements2;
}
```

It will first evaluate the `condition`, if `condition==true`, `statements1` will be evaluated, otherwise, `statements2` will be evaluated.

---

Back to your example:

```
if (true){
    if (false){
        System.out.println("true false");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("true true");
    }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
if (false){
    System.out.println("true false");
}
else{
    System.out.println("true true");
}
```

and is further equivalent to

```
System.out.println("true true");
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java , true and false are constants.

So a block starting  with

```
if(true)
```

will always be executed whereas a block starting with

```
if(false)
```

will never be executed

Doing something like

```
boolean bol = true;

... // more process here

if (bol) { 
 //execute the rest of the code
}
```

is different as the bol varaible can either be true or false, depending on the previous processing

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of an if statement is so:

```
if (expression) {
}
```

Inside the `()` you put an *expression* that can evaluate to `true` or `false`. If the expression evaluates to `true`, the if statement will execute the block of code underneath the `if`. Otherwise, your interpreter will move on to the `else` statement, where this can execute another `if` statement, or just default to some block of code.

In your example, the expression is simply `true`, and therefore always evaluates to `true`, so that if block always executes.

The same logic applies to `false`: `false` of course always evaluates to `false`, and so those blocks are never executed.